# Dropdown(toogler) do bootstrap 4 não ta funcionando

Tags: bootstrap, dropdown

Alguém poderia me dizer onde estou errando? a ordem do bootstrap e jquery tá correto e não mostra erro no console do navegador mas quando eu diminuo o tamanho da página , o dropdown nao expande.
código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge">
    <title>@yield('titulo')</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Aaa</a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-
            toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSite">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSite">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contato</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sobre</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Não é necessário adicionar RESOLVIDO no titulo, como pode ser visto no **[tour]**, você só precisa aceitar a resposta que lhe resolveu a duvida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro está aqui:

```js
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-
            toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSite">
```

Você deu uma quebra de linha no meio dos atributos da tag, mais especificamente, "**data-toggle**" do **button**. Tem que ficar assim:

```html
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSite">
```

Funcionando:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge">
    <title>@yield('titulo')</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Aaa</a>
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSite">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSite">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contato</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sobre</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, deu certo aqui, o erro era esse mesmo, as vezes sou muito desatento rs. Obrigado

Comment: Disponha. Não esqueça de marcar a pergunta como "resolvido".